# How to transform `std::tuple<T...>` to `std::tuple<U, T...>`

Tags: c++, tuples

I have a `std::tuple<T...>` object, such as `std::tuple<int, float> a {9,3.14}` and I need to create a `std::tuple<U, T...>` object, like `std::tuple<bool, int, float> b {true, 9, 3.14}` from `a`.

To be clear, I do not know `T...` neither `U`, so I am looking for a generic way.

I studied `std::tie`, `std::tuple_cat`, but I could not figure it out if any of them could be used for that.

Comment: Are you looking for `std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(true), a)`?

Comment: Just that! I tried `std::tuple_cat(true, a)`, but I do not remember why I did not try  `std::tuple_cat(std::make_tuple(true), a)`. May be I did not fully understood `std::tuple_cat`.

Comment: Note, using tuple_cat like this is simple, but causes _two_ copies of the newly added element (one into the 1-element tuple, and another into the final tuple).  I was writing an example to bypass this and got side-tracked before posting it, but the question was closed.  :(

Comment: Here is an example https://godbolt.org/z/cn7731fox